# Print output of cat statement in bash script loop

Tags: linux, bash, for-loop, cat

I'm trying to execute a command for each line coming from a cat command. I'm basing this on sample code I got from a vendor.

Here's the script:

```
for tbl in 'cat /tmp/tables'
do
   echo $tbl
done
```

So I was expecting the output to be each line in the file. Instead I'm getting this:

```
cat
/tmp/tables
```

That's obviously not what I wanted.

I'm going to replace the echo with an actual command that interfaces with a database.

Any help in straightening this out would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You are using the wrong type of quotes.

You need  to use the back-quotes rather than the single quote to make the argument being a program running and piping out the content to the forloop.

```
for tbl in `cat /tmp/tables` 
do 
    echo "$tbl"
done
```

Also for better readability (if you are using bash), you can write it as

```
for tbl in $(cat /tmp/tables) 
do 
    echo "$tbl"
done
```

If your expectations are to get each line (The for-loops above will give you each word), then you may be better off using `xargs`, like this

```
cat /tmp/tables | xargs -L1 echo
```

or as a loop

```
cat /tmp/tables | while read line; do echo "$line"; done
```

Comment: The last version has the advantage of removing whitespace, too.

Answer (score 5):

The single quotes should be backticks:

```
for tbl in `cat /etc/tables`
```

Although, this will not get you output/input by line, but by word.  To process line by line, you should try something like:

```
cat /etc/tables | while read line
    echo $line
done
```

Answer (score 3):

With *while* loop:

```
while read line
do
echo "$line"
done < "file"
```

Answer (score 3):

```
while IFS= read -r tbl; do echo "$tbl" ; done < /etc/tables
```

read [this](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor).

Answer (score 0):

You can do a lot of parsing in bash by redefining the IFS (Input Field Seperator), for example

```
IFS="\t\n"  # You must use double quotes for escape sequences. 
for tbl in `cat /tmp/tables` 
do 
    echo "$tbl"
done
```

Comment: '\t\n'? Have you actually tried it in bash? It will split on '\', 't', 'n', unhelpful.

Comment: Single quotes do not allow for escaping. Use double quotes. `"\t\n"` Otherwise, single quotes will literally preserve the meaning of '\', 't', 'n.